# What are "Numerically Weighted Transcripts"?

Tags: funding, australia

I was reading about a [postgraduate scholarship](https://internationaleducation.gov.au/Endeavour%20program/Scholarships-and-Fellowships/Pages/default.aspx). As part of application for the scholarship, a "numerically weighted" transcript is required.

This is what my B.S. trancript looks like:
[(A part of my transcript HERE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCXkM.jpg)

It shows, on a single page, all the courses taken in all the semesters, Letter Grades (LG) and Grade Points (GP) secured in the courses, Credit Hours (CHr) of the courses, all my re-attempts, as well as GPA secured in the semesters, and final CGPA --- i.e. absolutely no information is hidden.
Now my question is:

Is this what a "numerically weighted academic transcript" is; as required for the scholarship?

Comment: An "official" transcript is very likely one which is sent to them directly from the school, and not from you.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE! We don't usually include "thanks" in questions, so I've edited it out of yours.

Comment: @PeterShor I would think an official transcript is any original transcript or copy which includes a valid stamp and signature from the school. Because in some cases students can print out their transcript themselves through an online system as well (that wouldn't be official).

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be explained in a [FAQ from a previous year](http://studylib.net/doc/5921097/2015-round-frequently-asked-questions) for this scholarship.

> I do not have numerically weighted academic transcripts, can I still apply?
>
> We require academic transcripts/official documentation showing specific subjects and how your overall grades were obtained. We require evidence of the progress of your studies in individual subjects, so that we can see, for example, whether your strongest subjects were in the areas in which you propose  your specific research inquiry, or whether your grades improved over the course of your  years  of  study.  We  require  evidence  of  the  subjects  you  completed  and  of  their  actual  value,  not  just  the  one  figure  for  their composite value. This  information  is  required  so  that  panel  members  can  make  appropriate  and  informed  recommendations  on  the  ‘academic achievement’ selection criteria. We would suggest you contact your University to obtain this information as your application would be deemed ineligible without this information.

So they want a transcript which has grades for every subject you took (and not just an overall rating, which is all that some very prestigious schools in England provide).

It sounds to me that what "numerically weighted academic transcript" actually means to them is one that has an overall GPA, as well as all the numbers that went into computing this value. Most schools provide this in their standard transcript; the most notable exceptions being the few U.K. schools noted above—I would guess that these schools are the ones that this criterion is directed towards.

Comment: Yes, I have read FAQs, but could not understand this point.
So in my case, if you have had a look at the transcript picture above, is it 'numerically weighted'? Or does it need to describe the _marks_ obtained (out of 100, for example) in every subject, as well as the grade (GP or LG) in the subject?

Comment: @Asim my guess is when they say weighted they mean for each course you multiple the GP by CHr, sum all of those together, and divide by the total CHr (thus you weight the GPs by the CHr value). I believe your transcript already does that. But let's wait for an actual Australian to confirm.

Comment: @Asim Yes my understanding is the "GP" and "CHr" columns in that transcript *clearly* shows all of the grades and how they are weighted. You should be able to calculate your GPA directly from those two numbers: the weighted (by CHr) average of the GP.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you! That's what I wanted to be sure about.